# Translation of “It should not have been like this.”?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, subjunctive

> It should not have been like this.

What would be the correct translation for the above English sentence to German? The sense here is that you find yourself in an awkward or rather miserable situation and then you talk to yourself and say that “it should not have been like this”.

I have come up with the following but I am afraid I may be utterly wrong,

1. > Es sollte nicht so gewesen haben.
2. > Es hätte nicht so sein sollten.

Answer (score 4):

Idiomatically I'd probably say either:

> Das war [aber] nicht so vorgesehen/gedacht.

or, slightly different nuance:

> Das habe ich mir [aber] [irgendwie] anders vorgestellt.

Answer (score 0):

I as a german would say:

> Es hätte nicht so sein sollen.

or in another WO:

> Es hätte so nicht sein sollen.

Comment: Or to put more emphasis on the "so", which I believe is more common: "So hätte es nicht sein sollen.".

Comment: Was ist eine WO?

Comment: @Robert: Ich nehme an, es handelt sich um eine Abkürzung für *word order*, die ist mir aber noch nie begegnet.

Comment: @Robert  Ja das sollte für word order stehen das habe ich damals im Englischunterricht aufgeschnappt, dachte das wäre allgemein geläufig, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Two proposals (both more in the colloquial style, but for a conversation with oneself, that should be fine)

> Das hätte ganz anders laufen sollen
>
> Das ging ja
>
> - ordentlich daneben
> - in die Hose
> - nach hinten los